# Visual Studio 2010 XML tag matching - stopped working?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I've got a couple of XML files which I'm working on, and when I click at the start of a tag (`<`**|**`tag>`, where **|** is the cursor), the corresponding tag isn't highlighted. It works for other XML style languages though...

However, when I type `<tag>`, it highlights and places the closing tag (also highlighted) to the right of my cursor as usual.

The highlighting works fine in XAML files. I tried changing my XML file to HTML to see if tag matching occurred there, and it did! Changing it back to XML though, and the feature was lost.

I've tried turning Automatic delimiter highlighting off and on again (Tools->Options -> Text Editor->General -> Automatic delimiter highlighting), but that's not made any improvement.

Not really sure what else to try. Or, indeed, if it ever did it in the first place for XML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or, indeed, if it ever did it in the first place for XML.

It doesn't do it on my machine.  And I didn't futz with it.

So I don't think it ever did.